# SystemJS Transpiler - where would it be used

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6

I'm creating a project which uses SystemJS/JSPM.
I'm also using TypeScript.

Now TypeScript has the option of compiling JS using SystemJS Modules - which I'm doing and all is good.  I've created TS modules and then imported modules from JSPM - at which point TS uses SystemJS to import those modules in Javascript.

Where I get confused is why SystemJS then also has the option of using TypeScript and/or Babel as a Transpiler.

Are there ready made JSPM/NPM modules out there that come in Typescript form or ES6 form that SystemJS would then use one of these Transpilers to build Javascript / or transpile down to ES5?

Or am I missing something entirely here?

As a side note there's no systemjs tag or transpiler tag on programmers exchange.

Comment: Many packages include multiple distribution formats as well as their source code, using the transpiler option allows you to process these directly (in most cases). There are a variety of reasons you would do this including allowing the systemjs-builder to apply advanced rollup optimizations for production bundling or to work directly with the source, say for debugging purposes, during development. I have done this with the ESRI-Leaflet packages. Good point about the need for a systemjs tag.